# Trocar botão após click em JSF

Tags: jsf, mvc, java

Fala pessoal estou com o seguinte problema, tenho estes dois botões que fazem:

X : Retira o valor de um grafico
+ : Adiciona o valor de um grafico

[image: Foto1]

Preciso que fique assim: Quando eu clicar no botão X

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele troque para o botão +, pois eles tem funções diferentes como podem notar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha view está assim atualmente:

```
<p:column width="30">
                <p:commandButton id="valorSelect" value="x"
                    actionListener="#{statusView.selecionarView}" update=":novoform:grafico" >
                    <f:attribute name="projetoSelecionadoNaView" value="#{projeto}" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton value="+"
                    actionListener="#{statusView.addView}" update=":novoform:grafico" >
                    <f:attribute name="projetoSelecionadoNaView" value="#{projeto}" />
                </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se entendi bem, você quer que quando o usuário clique em um botão ele desapareça e o outro fique no lugar. Você pode usar o atributo 'rendered do JSF ajunto com uma expressão ou variável booleana que alterne no momento que vocês desejar. Eu peguei mais ou menos o seu código e fiz uma exemplo já dentro de uma tabela:

```
 <h:form id="novoform">

        <p:dataTable id="grafico" value="#{trocaBotaoBean.listaTeste}" var="nome" >
            <p:column headerText="Action" >
                <p:commandButton rendered="#{!trocaBotaoBean.adicionandoValor}"
                                 id="valorSelect" value="x" actionListener="#{trocaBotaoBean.adicionar()}"
                                 update=":novoform:grafico" />
                <p:commandButton rendered="#{trocaBotaoBean.adicionandoValor}"
                                 actionListener="#{trocaBotaoBean.retirar()}"
                                 value="+"
                                 update=":novoform:grafico" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="VALORES">
                <h:outputText value="#{nome}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
```

ManagedBean:

```
public class TrocaBotaoBean {

private boolean adicionandoValor;

public TrocaBotaoBean() {

}

public void adicionar() {
    this.adicionandoValor = true;
}

public void retirar() {
    this.adicionandoValor = false;
}

public boolean isAdicionandoValor() {
    return adicionandoValor;
}

public List<String> getListaTeste() {
    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();
    nomes.add("ZEUS");
    nomes.add("THOR");
    nomes.add("RÁ");
    return nomes;
}
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Tá mas por exemplo: Se eu adicionar um valor ali vai sumir o outro botão só daquela linha ? acho que ele vai sumir todos os botões de todas as linahs...não acha ?

Comment: sim, se vc quer fazer isso individualmente, vc precisará de um pouco mais de código, por exemplo, ajustar o datable, o selection, selection mode, rowKey, alem disso, precisará usar um  <p:ajax que vai capturar a linha com evento 'rowSelect'. esses botões, não precisarão se repetir, basta joga-los no footer ou header ja q eles alterar somente o q foi selecionado. Acredito q seja dessa forma.